# Why is systemtap not generating the output necessary for flamegraph creation?

Tags: rhel5, systemtap, flamegraph

## **When executing stap for the purposes of generating flamegraph data, why is my out.stap-stacks missing process data?**

- OS: RHEL 5.10.0.2
- Kernel: 2.6.18-371.11.1.el5
- SystemTap: 1.8-6.el5

Packages installed:

systemtap-sdt-devel-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-devel-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-devel-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-runtime-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-sdt-devel-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-initscript-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-client-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-server-1.8-6.el5

systemtap-testsuite-1.8-6.el5

kernel-devel-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5

kernel-debug-devel-2.6.18-371.11.1.el5

Command used:

```
stap -s 32 -D MAXBACKTRACE=100 -D MAXSTRINGLEN=4096 -D MAXMAPENTRIES=10240 \
    -D MAXACTION=10000 -D STP_OVERLOAD_THRESHOLD=5000000000 --all-modules \
    -ve 'global s; probe timer.profile { s[backtrace()] <<< 1; } 
    probe end { foreach (i in s+) { print_stack(i);
    printf("\t%d\n", @count(s[i])); } } probe timer.s(60) { exit(); }' \
    > out.stap-stacks
```

Sample out.stap-stacks file:

0xffffffff8000e81a
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8004ab87
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8025d15d
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff80239356
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8004219a
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8000ca32
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8003214e
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff80013bc8
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff80232d41
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8001a4ca
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff80011db5
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8004aad2
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff800ec8bb
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff8003ead5
 0x0
        1
 0xffffffff80234c43
 0x0

Answer (score 1):

The `backtrace()` function is limited to kernel-space backtraces, and `print_stack()` maps only kernel-space addresses to symbols.  (I cannot explain why the 0xffffffff8* addresses weren't converted to the symbols; maybe some combination of ancient systemtap and ancient kernel?)

If you want to print userspace backtrace data too, you will need to use the `u*` family of backtrace-related functions.

See also https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/#profiling/pf4.stp for a similar script that includes userspace work.